# Anova loop in R

Tags: r, loops, anova

Im currently making a lot of ANOVA's in R and my code looks like this: 
My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Vial_nr = c(151L, 151L, 151L, 162L), Concentration = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "x", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    Line = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("20", "23", 
    "40", "73"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), Fly = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    Temp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("23", "29"
    ), class = "factor"), X0.5_sec = c(51.84, 41.28, 8.64, 28.8
    ), X1_sec = c(41.76, 8.64, 10.56, 42.72), X1.5_sec = c(42.72, 
    17.28, 10.08, 57.12), X2_sec = c(51.36, 29.76, 19.68, 71.52
    ), X2.5_sec = c(52.8, 44.64, 39.36, 69.12), X3_sec = c(55.68, 
    52.8, 58.08, 82.56), Vial = structure(c(138L, 138L, 138L, 
    149L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
    "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
    "40", "41", "42", "43", "47", "49", "50", "56", "57", "59", 
    "61", "62", "63", "64", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
    "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
    "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", 
    "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", 
    "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", 
    "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", 
    "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", 
    "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", 
    "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", 
    "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", 
    "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", 
    "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", 
    "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", 
    "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", 
    "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", 
    "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", 
    "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", 
    "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", 
    "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", 
    "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", 
    "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "254", 
    "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", 
    "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "273", 
    "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "461", "462", 
    "463", "464", "465", "466", "467", "468", "469", "470", "471", 
    "472", "473", "474", "475", "476", "477", "478", "479", "480", 
    "481", "482", "483", "484", "485", "486", "487", "488", "489", 
    "490", "491", "492", "493", "494", "495", "496", "497", "498", 
    "499", "500", "501", "502", "503", "504", "505", "506", "507", 
    "508", "509", "510", "511", "512", "513", "514", "515", "516", 
    "517", "518", "519", "520", "521", "522", "523", "524", "525", 
    "526", "527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", "533", "534", 
    "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", "540", "541", "542", "543", 
    "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", "549", "550"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Vial_nr", 
"Concentration", "Line", "Sex", "Fly", "Temp", "X0.5_sec", "X1_sec", 
"X1.5_sec", "X2_sec", "X2.5_sec", "X3_sec", "Vial"), row.names = 4:7, class = "data.frame")

dat <- read.table("Complete RING.txt", header =TRUE)  
str(dat)
dat$Vial <- as.factor(dat$Vial)
dat$Line <- as.factor(dat$Line)
dat$Fly <- as.factor(dat$Fly)  
dat$Temp <- as.factor(dat$Temp)
str(dat)

Line20af <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="a" & Sex=="f")
    Line20bf <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="b" & Sex=="f")
    Line20cf <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="c" & Sex=="f")
    Line20df <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="d" & Sex=="f")
    Line20ef <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="e" & Sex=="f")
    Line20xf <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="x" & Sex=="f")
    Line20yf <- subset(dat, Line=="20" & Concentration=="y" & Sex=="f")
    out20 <- matrix(ncol=6, nrow=7)
    colnames(out20) <- colnames(Line20af)[7:12]
    rownames(out20) <- paste0("Concentration", 1:7)
    for(i in 1:6){
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20af[,6+i],Line20af$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[1,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20bf[,6+i],Line20bf$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[2,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20cf[,6+i],Line20cf$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[3,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20df[,6+i],Line20df$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[4,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20ef[,6+i],Line20ef$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[5,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20xf[,6+i],Line20xf$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[6,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
      tmp <- data.frame(Line20yf[,6+i],Line20yf$Temp)
      colnames(tmp)<-c("y","c")
      fit1=lm(y~c,data=tmp) 
      fit2=lm(y~1,data=tmp) 
      out20[7,i]<-anova(fit1,fit2)$"Pr(>F)"[2]
    }
    xtable(out20)
```

But doing this a lot of times just copy paste seems really dumb, i have tried to make temp data fields so i dont get to many datasets, however that doesn't  yield any results. I have also tried to make a for loop using unique() on Concentration to make create the new datasets but then R doesn't print any results. Is there a way to optimize this piece of script to streamline my workflow and not overflow my workspace?

EDIT: added dput of data snip

Comment: Take `head(dat)` and post it here - that gives a reproducible example that we can work on and help you via.

Comment: Added to the top now

Comment: So, you are trying to fit linear model with `X*` as response and `Temp` as predictor. Why don't you give all the `X*` as response at once, `lm` will handle multiple response. Further you don't have to fit the null model since ANOVA will give you how far the model is from the null model.